# Update an Oracle table using another ungrouped table

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update, correlated-subquery

The scenario involves two tables with the following structures :

```
>table e1:


Id    Name    Addr
---------------------
1     Ramas
2     Sam
3     Musa
4     Sebi



>table e1_addr:



Id   Addr    Mod_Date
-----------------------
1    Gzb     10-05-2018
1    Dli     18-05-2018
2    Gzb     25-05-2018
2    Dli     22-05-2018
3    Gzb     09-05-2018
3    Dli     05-05-2018
4    Gzb     14-05-2018
4    Dli     24-05-2018
```

table `e1` has 4 personnel with no updated addresses in `address` column.
table `e_addr` has updated address record for each id with `mod_date` column having the date the record was entered.

I need to update table `e1` so that its `addr` column has the value from the `e1_addr` table with maximum `mod_date`.

On my part, I have tried to fetch `addr` from `e1_addr` table corresponding to the `max(mod_date)` but cannot achieve the desired result.

Desired output is as follows :

```
Final Table :


Id   Name   Addr
------------------
1   Ramas   Dli
2   Sam     Gzb
3   Musa    Gzb
4   Sebi    Dli
```

Any and all help would be apprecited.

Please inform if i should give in some more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `keep`:

```
update e1
    set addr = (select max(a.addr) keep (dense_rank first order by mod_date desc)
                from ei_addr a
                where e1.id = a.id
               );
```

I would suggest that you not store the address in two places and simply fetch the latest address when you query the `e1` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query to update `Addr` column.

*windows function* with `ROW_NUMBER` to get Rownumber is 1 on `e1_addr`,which mean `MAX` `Mod_Date`.

then update `e1.addr`.

```
UPDATE 
(
  SELECT t.addr as OLD,t2.addr as NEW
  FROM e1 t 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT t2.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY t2.Mod_Date desc) rn
    FROM e1_addr t2 
  ) t2 on t.id = t2.id
  where t2.rn = 1
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

or another update query you can try subquery.

```
UPDATE e1 t1
SET t1.addr = (SELECT t2.addr
FROM 
  (
    SELECT t2.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY t2.Mod_Date desc) rn
    FROM e1_addr t2 
  ) t2
  WHERE t2.rn = 1 and t1.id = t2.id
)
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e14f5/1

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist, the `MERGE` syntax wasn't mentioned yet:

```
MERGE INTO e1 USING (SELECT ID, MAX(addr) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY mod_date DESC) AS newest_addr
                       FROM e1_addr GROUP BY ID) q ON (e1.ID = q.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e1.addr = q.newest_addr;
```

This subquery selects the newest address for each id:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(addr) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY mod_date DESC) AS newest_addr
  FROM e1_addr GROUP BY ID;

ID newest_addr  
1  Dli
2  Gzb 
3  Gzb
4  Dli
```

... and `MERGE` looks up each `id` in the subquery, and if it finds a match, it updates the `addr`.

Some people love it, some hate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

**Step1:** Take id and max date from address table
**Step 2:** Join on id and max date with the address table to get the address
**Step 3** Join this table with my e1 table to get the final output

```
select p.*,q.addr
from
e1 p
left join
(
  select a.id,b.addr
  from
     (select id,max(mod_date) as updated_date
     from e1_addr
     group by id ) a
  left join
     e1_addr b
  on a.id = b.id and a.updated_date = b.mod_date
) q
on p.id = q.id;
```

Let me know in case of any concerns

Comment: The question says "update". I don't see an update here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all the answers and different ways you posted to solve the query while i found a much simpler way to do same after having a discussion with one of my juniors. I felt pity for myself.

```
update e1 a set a.addr=(select addr from e1_addr b
where mod_date= (select max(mod_date) from e1_addr
where id=  a.id ));
```

Thanks for all the support guys!